# Determine number of pages in a PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-2.0

I need to determine the number of pages in a specified PDF file using C# code (.NET 2.0).  The PDF file will be read from the file system, and not from an URL.  Does anyone have any idea on how this could be done?  Note: Adobe Acrobat Reader is installed on the PC where this check will be carried out.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You'll need a PDF API for C#. iTextSharp is one possible API, though better ones might exist.

**iTextSharp Example**

You must install iTextSharp.dll as a reference. Download iTextsharp from SourceForge.net This is a complete working program using a console application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.xml;
namespace GetPages_PDF
{
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
      {
       // Right side of equation is location of YOUR pdf file
        string ppath = "C:\\aworking\\Hawkins.pdf";
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(ppath);
        int numberOfPages = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
        Console.WriteLine(numberOfPages);
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: so are you saying "here's what I recommend, but actually there are betetr ways to do this"?

Comment: Thank, Darkdog, after looking at PDFLib and iTextSharp, I ended up using iTextSharp:


                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath);
                int numberOfPages = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;

Hope this helps someone facing the same problem.

Comment: @liang it's one-based. There is no page zero.

Comment: It is now iText7 and the code to extract the page count is PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(fileName)) and then pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); You can get the project from NuGet packages.

Comment: Don't forget to dispose the PdfReader: `using(var pdfReader = new PdfReader(ppath)) { ... }`

Comment: You should note that iText license is AGPL which means if you use it, then you need to either buy a commercial license, or publish your source code for free. See https://itextpdf.com/en/blog/technical-notes/how-do-i-make-sure-my-software-complies-agpl-how-can-i-use-itext-free  and https://opensource.google/docs/using/agpl-policy/

Answer (score 46):

This should do the trick:

```
public int getNumberOfPdfPages(string fileName)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fileName)))
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"/Type\s*/Page[^s]");
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(sr.ReadToEnd());

        return matches.Count;
    }
}
```

From [Rachael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320281/determine-number-of-pages-in-a-pdf-file-using-c-net-2-0/595458#595458) and [this one](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/726.html) too.

Comment: Barrett, thanks for providing example code. +1

Comment: I don't think this will always give the correct count. It also will not work on encrypted PDFs.

Comment: @TimB I saved an encrypted PDF and this works on it.

Comment: @w0lf It seems you are right. The page objects are one of the few things in an encrypted PDF that are readable without the password.

Comment: Didn't work for me - copied and pasted exactly as shown. It returned a value of 216, when the PDF actually had 111 pages.

Comment: Works great but slower than the iTextSharp solution.

Comment: PDF uses versioned objects, and can also include deleted objects if the PDF hasn't been cleaned up, so it is possible to have Page objects that aren't actually linked into the PDF or that have been replaced with a newer version.  This is why using a maintained PDF library is a better idea than doing it yourself.

Comment: I know this is old question, but I was searching for way of getting total count of pages, but I noticed that I must read whole document. I have really large files and I'd like to get page count without reading whole pdf. Can this be done without external dependencies?

Comment: I know this is a super old question and answer, but I found this answer on Google a while ago and just came back to it. This answer works but will cause an OutOfMemoryException in big PDFs (i.e. a PDF with 150 images at 300dpi). The iTextSharp answer provided by darkdog works perfectly

Comment: Does this support tif files?

Comment: It does not always give correct answer, but most of the time. thanks

Answer (score 8):

found a way at http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/21866-Count-pages-PDF-file.aspx
this does not require purchase of a pdf library

Comment: Rachael, finally reviewed this question, and checked out your link.  Thanks, one to try next time this problem comes up!  +1

Answer (score 4):

I have used [pdflib](http://www.pdflib.com) for this.

```
    p = new pdflib();

    /* Open the input PDF */
    indoc = p.open_pdi_document("myTestFile.pdf", "");
    pageCount = (int) p.pcos_get_number(indoc, "length:pages");
```

Answer (score 3):

One Line:

```
int pdfPageCount = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("example.pdf").Split(new string[] { "/Type /Page" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Count()-2;
```

Recommended:
[ITEXTSHARP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Comment: Works well for my files. It is fast enough for my need but I wonder how is performance compared to the regex solution posted by @Barrett

Comment: doesn't work for me, I get -1, but hte PDF file has 32 pages.

Answer (score 2):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) may be used to accomplish the task.

Here is sample code:

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
document.Open("file.pdf");
int pageCount = document.PageCount;
```

The library will parse as little as possible so performance should be ok.

Disclaimer: I work for Bit Miracle.

Comment: I don't want to be sarcastic, but you should check your performance claim.
I tried on a 250 pages PDF, 216Mo, and it was nearly 20x slower than PDF-Sharp, just to get the page count, using your example

Answer (score 0):

I have good success using CeTe Dynamic PDF products.  They're not free, but are well documented.  They did the job for me.

http://www.dynamicpdf.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've used the code above that solves the problem using regex and it works, but it's quite slow. It reads the entire file to determine the number of pages.

I used it in a web app and pages would sometimes list 20 or 30 PDFs at a time and in that circumstance the load time for the page went from a couple seconds to almost a minute due to the page counting method.

I don't know if the 3rd party libraries are much better, I would hope that they are and I've used pdflib in other scenarios with success.

Comment: Ryan, I have used the iTextSharp library to solve this problem, and found it to give decent performance.  You could also look at PDFSharp.  As for the issues with the regex solution, it is another example of regular expressions causing more problems than they solve - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001016.html

Comment: Agreed. I didn't see your note until after, but I replaced the RegEx function with one using iTextSharp as you recommend and there was a huge improvement in performance. 

Based on my tests the iTextSharp method is at least 5x faster than the RegEx method and usually a lot more than that, at least when I'm calculating for a number of PDF files at the same time (i.e. loading a page with multiple PDFs listed).

Comment: If performance is a problem, you might want to try a command line utility such as PDFLeo (http://www.rockpdf.com). A command like "pdfleo -i myfile.pdf | grep "Number of Pages" takes less than 1 second on 300 pages file.