# How to get the number of pages inside each pdf document inside a directory

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, pdf, c#-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine Number of Pages in a PDF File using C# (.NET 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320281/determine-number-of-pages-in-a-pdf-file-using-c-sharp-net-2-0)

I used the following code to get the count of number of pdf files in a directory.

```
    var extensions = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
    {
        ".pdf", 
    };
    var baseDir = BatchFolderPath;
    var pdfFilesCount = Directory.EnumerateFiles(baseDir)
                                 .Count(filename =>
                                        extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(filename)));
```

I don't know how to get the number of pages inside each pdf document inside a directory. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to use a library to open each PDF file and grab the number of pages it contains.

Comment: This is not possible without a third party library.

Comment: it's possible but more work than it's worth, and will almost certainly lead to a less robust solution. That said, you can look for the obj definition without the word 'parent' that has 'count' 'type' and 'pages' in it which should catch most cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question like has been already asked Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320281/determine-number-of-pages-in-a-pdf-file-using-c-sharp-net-2-0). 
Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**
This is how you can find the number of pages in each pdf file present in your specified directory:

```
using System;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int PgCount = 0;
            string[] PdfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\MyFolder\", "*.pdf");
            Console.WriteLine("{0} PDF Files in directory", PdfFiles.Length.ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < PdfFiles.Length; i++)
            {
                PgCount = GetNumberOfPages(PdfFiles[i]);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} File has {1} pages", PdfFiles[i], PgCount.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static int GetNumberOfPages(String FilePath)
        {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(FilePath); 
            return pdfReader.NumberOfPages; 
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to download itextsharp.dll from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) and include that in References.

Comment: I saw that answer. But I don't know how to loop over multiple files. They given for straight single file. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: @John I have edited my answer to include a code sample. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries to work with pdf from c#.
Consider

1. [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/)
2. [Report.NET](http://report.sourceforge.net/)
3. [SharpPDF](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/)
4. [PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/)
5. [PDFjet Open Source Edition](http://pdfjet.com/os/edition.html)