# How to extract the amount of pages of a pdf in c#

Tags: c#, itext

I need to extract the numner of pages of a pdf in c#. Actually I trying a bit with [itextsharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) but there only a method where i can extract the page size (the rectangle) but nothing where i can see the number of pages. Any idea?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("starting");
        String filename = "d:\\tmp\\t1.pdf";

        if (File.Exists(filename)){
            byte[] pdfFile = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile);

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a reader.NumberOfPages() method which you can us. Its a duplicate question: [Determine number of pages in a PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320281/determine-number-of-pages-in-a-pdf-file)

Comment: Then flag is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your problem:

```
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("starting");
            String filename = "d:\\tmp\\t1.pdf";

            if (File.Exists(filename)){
                byte[] pdfFile = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile);
                int numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
                Console.WriteLine(numberOfPages);
            }

       }
   }
```